# Bootstrap 3.x Navbar not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 Navbar properly expands in full screen and on a browser of small width  in a desktop pc and mobile browsers it shrinks proper, HOWEVER when using the Toggle navigation button it doesnt slide down... Ive attempted to use the same code in the example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar ... other than my own personal includes, all the css, js and code structure mimic the example page... Can any twitter bootstrappers out there give me a hand? Blessings

URL to test page: http://www.autoexcelente.com/test/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Autoexcelente - Test Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Placeholder page to test user interface, includes, styles" />


    <link href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/css/proprietary.css"          rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/css/mytwitter.css"            rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Twitter                                            -->
    <script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/autoexcelente.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=4" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Google Map                                         -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/googlemap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/ico/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" />
    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/css/newsticker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var _scroll = {
            delay: 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            items: 1,
            duration: 0.07,
            timeoutDuration: 0,
            pauseOnHover: 'immediate'
        };

        $('#ticker-2').carouFredSel({
            width: 1000,
            align: true,
            circular: true,
            items: {
                width: 'variable',
                height: 35,
                visible: 2
           },
           scroll: _scroll
        });

        $('.caroufredsel_wrapper').css('width', '100%');
        });
    </script>

  </head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-42639445-1', 'autoexcelente.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/es/">
            <div class="brand_image" rel="tooltip" title="Auto Excelente - Su concesionario de autos de confianza en el coraz&oacute;n de la Avenida 65 de Infanter&iacute;a, San Ju&aacute;n y Carolina, Puerto Rico. Tel&eacute;fono (787)750-1400 / (787)550-6991">
           </div>
       </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/" rel="tooltip" title="Inventario de Autos Nuevos y Usados">
                    Inventario
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/servicio_automotriz/" rel="tooltip" title="Reparaci&oacute;n y Servicio Automotriz">
                    Servicio Automotriz
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/contactenos/" rel="tooltip" title="Cont&aacute;ctenos y vis&iacute;tenos en el coraz&oacute;n de la 65
 de Infanter&iacute;a, Carolina y San Ju&aacute;n, Puerto Rico.">
                    Cont&aacute;ctenos
                </a>
            </li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/#!/pages/Autoexcelente/455026431234764" data-width="200" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>            </li>
            <li>
                <map name="map_buttons">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="31,8,63,40" href="mailto:autoexcelentepr@gmail.com"
                        alt="Correo Electr&oacute;nico: autoexcelentepr@gmail.com"
                        rel="tooltip" title="Correo Electr&oacute;nico: autoexcelentepr@gmail.com">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="72,8,104,40" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/"
                        alt="Navigate AutoExcelente in English!"
                        rel="tooltip" title="Navigate AutoExcelente in English!">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="113,8,145,40" href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/test/"
                        alt="&iexcl;Navega AutoExcelente en Espa&ntilde;ol!"
                        rel="tooltip" title="&iexcl;Navega AutoExcelente en Espa&ntilde;ol!">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="31,47,63,80" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Autoexcelente/455026431234764"
                        alt="&iexcl;Visite nuestra p&aacute;gina en Facebook!"
                        rel="tooltip" title="&iexcl;Visite nuestra p&aacute;gina en Facebook!">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="72,47,104,80" href="https://twitter.com/autoexcelente"
                        alt="&iexcl;Ent&eacute;rese los ultimos tweets de Autoexcelente!"
                        rel="tooltip" title="&iexcl;Ent&eacute;rese los ultimos tweets de Autoexcelente!">
                    <area shape="rect"
                        coords="113,47,145,80" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/Autoexcelente?feature=watch"
                        alt="&iexcl;Hechese un vistazo a nuestro canal en YouTube!"
                        rel="tooltip" title="&iexcl;Hechese un vistazo a nuestro canal en YouTube!">
                </map>
                <img src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/img/ui_contact_ autoexcelente.png" width="180" height="89" border="0" usemap="#map_buttons" alt="linea%20cliente%20del%20carro%20barato%20(787)750-1400%20autoexcelentepr@gmail.com" />
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<hr/>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div>
        <dl id="ticker-2">
            <dt><a class="tel_dt" href="tel:7877501400">(787) 750 - 1400</a></dt>
                 <dd class="outer_dd">
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/hyundai/accent-407/2013_hyundai_accent-132/">2013 Hyundai Accent </a>
                    <span class="middle_dd"><a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/ford/freestar-1061/2006_ford_freestar-51/">2006 Ford Freestar </a></span>
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/volkswagen/beetle-874/2006_volkswagen_beetle-163/">2006 Volkswagen Beetle </a>
                 </dd>
           <dt><a class="tel_dt" href="tel:7879880440">(787) 988 - 0440</a></dt>
                 <dd class="outer_dd">
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/toyota/rav+4-838/2006_toyota_rav+4-10/">2006 Toyota Rav 4 </a>
                    <span class="middle_dd"><a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/ford/freestyle-320/2005_ford_freestyle-52/">2005 Ford Freestyle </a></span>
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/mitsubishi/lancer-625/2010_mitsubishi_lancer-121/">2010 Mitsubishi Lancer </a>
                 </dd>
           <dt><a class="tel_dt" href="tel:7877174202">(787) 717 - 4202</a></dt>
                 <dd class="outer_dd">
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/dodge/grand+caravan-251/2009_dodge_grand+caravan-99/">2009 Dodge Grand Caravan </a>
                    <span class="middle_dd"><a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/mitsubishi/eclipse-619/2011_mitsubishi_eclipse-110/">2011 Mitsubishi Eclipse </a></span>
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/nissan/versa-669/2012_nissan_versa-150/">2012 Nissan Versa </a>
                 </dd>
           <dt><a class="tel_dt" href="tel:7875506991">(787) 550 - 6991</a></dt>
                 <dd class="outer_dd">
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/bmw/3+series-69/2004_bmw_3+series-62/">2004 BMW 3 Series </a>
                    <span class="middle_dd"><a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/ford/mustang-327/2007_ford_mustang-143/">2007 Ford Mustang </a></span>
                    <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/inventario/mazda/5-547/2007_mazda_5-/">2007 Mazda 5 </a>
                 </dd>
             </dl>
         </div>
    </div>

<br/><br/>        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/es/" >Autoexcelente 2014</a></p>
            <p>
                <a href="." >Sobre Nosotros</a> - 
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/terminos_de_servicio/" >Terminos de Servicio</a> - 
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/poliza_de_privacidad/" >Poliza de Privacidad</a> -
                <a href="http://www.autoexcelente.com/mapa/" >Mapa de el Lugar</a>
            </p>
        </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must include jquery before you include bootstrap.js.
So instead of

```
    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You should try

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Btw.: You should also check the developer-tools output (eg. chrome F12) and check for errors and resources which can not be loaded. This way you might have found out whats going wrong by your self ;) There are some other issues though. Check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

On you Page, JS inspect element throws error :

> Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery

You have **incorrect order for including the files**.

First include jquery, then, do bootstrap, change this :

```
<script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.autoexcelente.com/assets/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```